# Angularjs: onerror is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

onerror is not working in IE only, rest browser it showing correctly.

Here is my code:

```
<img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/uploads/{{obj.img}}" onerror="this.src='<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/default_avatar.png'"/>
```

My understanding: Here i am trying to use onerror when images are available in **uploads** folder than script need to take a default image to show on browser. But it is displaying default images even though images are available in **uploads** folder. And this issue is with only IE 10 & edge. It is working fine in Crome and firefox.

Comment: Change `src` to `ng-src`.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar. Its working. but how come its working in other browsers without ng-src

Comment: IE is not a browser, it's a monstrous html viewer that enjoys torturing web developers